# PhoneGap - storing an image, then getting its base64encoded data

Tags: cordova

I am using the PhoneGap Camera API to take a picture and store it using `destinationType.FILE_URI`. This portion is working. I can subsequently take the path provided and set it as the src of an HTML image, and the image appears.

Later in the code, I want to grab the image, convert it to base64encoded data, and transmit it to the server. This is where the problem is.

I am getting `{"code" : 5}` (which, according to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/7f86cee8c9b76e0b), means it's an invalid URI) in my fail callback when using:

```js
fileSystem.root.getFile("content://media/external/images/media/4292", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

I don't understand why I can set an `img.src`, but phoneGap can't use the same URI to find the file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is because the Android OS has a URI handler for the `content://` protocol. The File API does not. However, there is a way for you to convert a `content://` type URI into a `FileEntry`. Use:

```js
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("content://media/external/images/media/4292", win, fail);
```

and the success callback `win` will be called with a `FileEntry` for you.

Comment: But how to display the image then? I have been trying with fullPath, nativeUrl etc but nothing working for me :(