# Cordova media-capture.captureImage plug-in not working + file not working with media-capture

Tags: cordova, plugins, file-io, phonegap-build

I've been developing an Android app in Cordova 3.3.0-0.3.1.  Using the tigbro JQMobile-Angular adapter.  Everything was going swimmingly until I tried to access files created by the media-capture plugin to make thumbnails.  Not able to get access to any of the files I'm creating... there is an open SO thread here:

[Reading a file created by the media capture plugin in Cordova - Creating Thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906026/reading-a-file-created-by-the-media-capture-plugin-in-cordova-creating-thumbna)

So a SO poweruser kindly offered to help by looking at the code, and asked me to make a smaller, simpler app in which to test.  This is where it gets weird.  I built a small app with the basic code using Phonegap (3.3).  Now I'm having problems with the media-capture plugin itself.  I can fire up the capture plugin, and take a photo.  But every time I push the accept checkmark in the capture process, the error handler is called with "3: Canceled".  I've tested on a Motorola Droid Razr MAXX and a Nexus 5, same result (although the Nexus 5 has slightly different fail behavior, it throws the error in the background but doesn't end the capture process).

I upgraded my Phonegap CLI to 3.4, and updated the platform of the project.  (Didn't update plugins as I don't see any documentation on that.)  No change.

Here's the additional weirdness.  If I rebuild the project as a Phonegap Build project (and build remotely), the JQMobile elements are broken but the capture plugin works!  (Still having problem accessing the files though.)

I noticed in the Cordova documentation that there were some updates to the plugins around not being able to use the file plugin with media-capture:

https://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/04/23/plugins.release.html

I think that because I am not specifying plugin versions in my full project that it should be using the most up-to-date plugins when I perform a local build.  Is that correct?  Should I update my Cordova 3.3 to 3.4.1?  And the platform as well?  Is there some danger to breaking my project?

Here is the link to the repo for the simple app:

https://github.com/marcsyp/thumbnail

Any ideas on some of these problems?

Comment: Upgraded to Cordova 3.4... big mistake.  I believe that Cordova 3.4 breaks the tigbro JQMobile-Angular adapter.  All the JQMobile code is totally broken.  Will be rolling back to 3.3.1.

Comment: Rolled back all my code and my cordova to 3.3.1-0.3.1, as well as the android platform, and the JQMobile stuff is still broken.  Haven't tried installing specific older plugin versions yet.

Comment: Though I did end up fixing this (see answer below), I decided to throw JqueryMobile on the ground and convert to Ionic.  It was a great decision and life is much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by rolling back to earlier versions of the plugins.