# Phonegap 3.4 - getFile fails

Tags: file, cordova

Upgraded my app to phonegap 3.4 and reading a text file (db.txt) in the root of the www folder now fails.
The following snippet used to work:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, this.gotFS, this.fail); 
this.gotFS = function(fileSystem) {
        console.log(fileSystem.name);
        fileSystem.root.getFile("../MyappName.app/www/db.txt", {create: false, exclusive: true}, file_reader.gotFileEntry, file_reader.fail);
    };
```

I've read [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) some changes occured in the file api but even if I use

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("db.txt", {create: false, exclusive: true}, file_reader.gotFileEntry, file_reader.fail);
        };
```

or

```
fileSystem.root.getFile(fileSystem.root.toURL()+"db.txt", {create: false, exclusive: true}, file_reader.gotFileEntry, file_reader.fail);
        };
```

file_reader.fail is always called with the error code of 5 which is ENCODING_ERR.

So basically how do you read a file in the root of the www folder with the new file api?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap - storing an image, then getting its base64encoded data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404040/phonegap-storing-an-image-then-getting-its-base64encoded-data)